# Как сделать валидацию пользователя?

Tags: java, исключения

У меня есть метод validateUser и он должен выбрасывать исключение AccessDeniedException ну который сам создал. И я написал таким образом

```
public static void validateUser(User user) throws AccessDeniedException{
        if(user.getAge()<18){
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Access Denied");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Age access granted");
        }
    }
```

И вопрос в том что как его вывести в методе *main*, ну допустим вводим логин и пароль юзера и если он меньше 18ти то должен вывести исключение. Ну я создал класс юзер с конструктором и геттерами. Весь код внизу(Не обращайте внимание на другие методы)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UserNotFoundException, AccessDeniedException{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите логин: ");
        String login = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите пароль: ");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();

        //TODO Проверить логин и пароль
//        User user = getUserByLoginAndPassword(login, password);
//        System.out.println("User: " + user.getLogin() + " - " + user.getEmail());
//        System.out.println("Access granted");
        //TODO Вызвать методы валидации пользователя
        
    }


    public static User[] getUsers(){
        User user1 = new User("john", "john@gmail.com", "pass", 24);
        User user2 = new User("mike", "mike@gmail.com", "qwerty", 22);
        User user3 = new User("steve", "steve@gmail.com", "asdfg", 23);
        return new User[]{user1, user2, user3};
    }

    public static User getUserByLoginAndPassword(String login, String password) throws UserNotFoundException{
        User[] users = getUsersList();
        for (User user : users) {
            if(login.equals(user.getLogin()) && password.equals(user.getPassword())){
                return user;
            }
        }
        throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found: " + login);
    }

    private static User[] getUsersList() {
        return getUsers();
    }

    public static void validateUser(User user) throws AccessDeniedException{
        if(user.getAge()<18){
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Access Denied");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Age access granted");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Уберите throws AccessDeniedException из объявления метода public static void validateUser(User user) throws AccessDeniedException

Comment: А зачем убирать? Я же потом не смогу выбросить исключение

Comment: Исключение вы бросаете в throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found: " + login); Если делаете это на уровне объявления метода, значит в методе вы не будете обрабатывать это исключение и передадите его в вызывающий класс